# CredentialsError: Could not load credentials from ChainableTemporaryCredentials in AWS-SDK v2 for Javascript

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, assume-role

I am trying to set up temporary credentials in the AWS-SDK v2 for Javascript:

```js
const aws = require('aws-sdk')

aws.config = new aws.Config({
  credentials: new aws.ChainableTemporaryCredentials({
    params: {
      RoleArn: roleArn, // Defined earlier
      RoleSessionName: sessionName, // Defined earlier
      DurationSeconds: 15 * 60
    },
    masterCredentials: new aws.Credentials({
      accessKeyId: accessKeyId, // Defined earlier
      secretAccessKey: awsSecretAccessKey // Defined earlier
    })
  }),
  region: 'us-east-1',
  signatureVersion: 'v4'
})

aws.config.getCredentials(function (err) {
  if (err) console.log(err.stack)
  else console.log('Access key:', aws.config.credentials.accessKeyId)
})
```

However, I'm keep getting the following error, which occurs when calling getCredentials:
`CredentialsError: Could not load credentials from ChainableTemporaryCredentials`

Note that it works fine if I set the `credentials` parameter to the master credentials instead of the temporary credentials, as shown below:

```js
aws.config = new aws.Config({
  credentials: new aws.Credentials({
    accessKeyId: accessKeyId, // Defined earlier
    secretAccessKey: awsSecretAccessKey // Defined earlier
  }),
  region: 'us-east-1',
  signatureVersion: 'v4'
})
```

Does anyone know what's causing this issue? Here's the documentation I was referencing:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Config.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Credentials.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/ChainableTemporaryCredentials.html

Answer (score 2):

I was finally able to figure out the cause of this error.

What led me to figure out the cause of the error was when I printed out the full error instead of just the most recent error. One of the properties of the error was:

```
originalError: {
          message: 'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.',
          code: 'SignatureDoesNotMatch',
          time: 2021-12-11T19:49:52.395Z,
          requestId: '402e4c32-7989-4287-a6a9-628bfc93f60f',
          statusCode: 403,
          retryable: false,
          retryDelay: 39.60145242362791
        }
```

So I realized the problem was that my masters credentials I provided were not correct!

I have actually always known that these credentials weren't correct, but for unit-testing purposes it seemed to work fine with these incorrect credentials as long as I didn't also supply the temporary credentials. But now I understand that the `getCredentials` function verifies the credentials with AWS if you're using temporary credentials, but *doesn't* verify with AWS when using *just* master credentials. That explains that strange behavior I was seeing.